# Form and Report on same page (Form as detail of selected report page)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am curently moving my small business app from ms access to Oracle Apex 20.

What I need is a page that shares both the report where I would select a row with record and form element at the top of page that would show details of the record.

Can someone give me an advice on how to start? I tried creating a blank page and inserting report and form elements manually but I am getting error `No Primary Key item has been defined for form region rep7`.

I suspect I need to connect the form and report with primary keys but don't know how. Closest I've been to solving my problem was watching this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-hoMcMIs9g&ab_channel=MostafizMitul

but I couldn't quite decipher it.

Thank you

Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you described it, it is a page whose type is **Master Detail**. Just follow the wizard, it'll create everything for you.

True - you can do it yourself, manually, but - why reinventing the wheel? The whole idea of Apex is to make things simpler for us, developers, to save us from *boring* actions we'd repeat over and over again. Let the wizard do it!